# Commerce Fee not being added to order total sent to payment processor

Tags: 7, commerce

I have followed the Commerce Fees module's instructions found at https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fees:

```
DOCUMENTATION

    Go to admin/commerce/config/fees and add a new fee type
    Add a rule at admin/config/workflow/rules
        Event: "Apply a fee to a given order".
        Set the conditions.
        Action: "Apply a fee to an order".
            Entity data selector: "commerce-order".
            Fee: Your fee type.
            Set amounts, currency and taxes as necessary.

Notice: if using fees based on payment type, be sure to move the payment type pane to a screen before the review pane on admin/commerce/config/checkout so that customers can see the fee before accepting.
```

The Fee shows up in the cart contents on checkout but that fee is not added to the order total that is sent to the payment processor not show in the orders view. It's like the fee is not actually added to the total, except for in the cart content view on the checkout page.

Any idea of what I am missing?

Comment: I would not rely on a module that its on beta and the last commit was in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look for the issue https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fees/issues/2191191, maybe a patch can help you.